# When is the btree created when adding an index to a MySQL 5.5 table?

Tags: mysql, b-tree

I have quite a big table in MySQL 5.5, ~200M rows, and I want to add an index to one of the columns in this table (btree type). The column is of type integer and contains a wide distribution of integers.

My question is when is the btree computed?

When I execute the simple create index query:

```
ALTER TABLE bigtable ADD INDEX (column3);
```

It returns immediately. Is the computing of the btree happening in the background? I can't imagine that MySQL is that fast at creating a btree of ~200M values with a wide distribution of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**.

Long Answer: A look at the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) for ALTER_TABLE reveals the following:

> In most cases, ALTER TABLE makes a temporary copy of the original table. MySQL waits for other operations that are modifying the table, then proceeds. It incorporates the alteration into the copy, deletes the original table, and renames the new one. While ALTER TABLE is executing, the original table is readable by other sessions (with the exception noted shortly). Updates and writes to the table that begin after the ALTER TABLE operation begins are stalled until the new table is ready, then are automatically redirected to the new table without any failed updates. The temporary copy of the original table is created in the database directory of the new table. This can differ from the database directory of the original table for ALTER TABLE operations that rename the table to a different database.

So, when you create your index, the index is being created on a temporary copy of the table, which is then imported in place of the now dropped original table when it completes.